# Importing NHL JSON data into R and formatting

Tags: r, json, api

I am trying to import JSON data from the NHLs API into R and organize nicely into a table for which I will be able to reference the stats by player (player names being the rows) and I could use some pointers.

Data: https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/skater/summary?isAggregate=false&isGame=false&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22:%22points%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D,%7B%22property%22:%22gamesPlayed%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22%7D,%7B%22property%22:%22playerId%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22%7D%5D&start=0&limit=100&factCayenneExp=gamesPlayed%3E=1&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and%20seasonId%3C=20202021%20and%20seasonId%3E=20202021

Sample of what the JSON data looks like:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Poid.png

Comment: Use: `answer <- jsonlite::fromJSON( ##URL goes here##)`, then grab the data part of the response:  `answer$data`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.